# Python multiprocessing module do not work

Tags: python, gevent

i am trying to write a spider with **multiprocessing** module

here is my python code:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import multiprocessing
import requests


class SpiderWorker(object):


    def __init__(self, q):
        self._q = q

    def run(self):

        def _crawl_item(url):
            requests.get("http://www.baidu.com")
            if respon.ok:
                print respon.url

        while True:
            rst = self._q.get()
            _crawl_item(rst)


def general_worker():

    q = multiprocessing.Queue()

    CPU_COUNT = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    worker_processes = [
        multiprocessing.Process(target=SpiderWorker(q).run)
        for i in range(CPU_COUNT)
    ]

    map( lambda process: process.start(), worker_processes )

    return q, worker_processes
```

maybe it is my process way wrong
every time i run this code, my process tell me

```
<Process(Process-1, stopped[SIGSEGV])>
```

hope love it

Comment: Sorry to nag, but five days have passed and there's no reaction from you. Did you manage to solve the issue yourself? If not, then did you identify the actual reason why your processes fail?

Answer (score 2):

The major problem here is that you don't have any information on *why* your processes fail. It could be gevent, but it could just as easily be something else. So learning the actual reason why your processes get terminated is the first step before doing anything else.

What you need is [`multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#logging):

```
class SpiderWorker(object):
    # ...
    def run(self):
        logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
        logger.setLevel(multiprocessing.SUBDEBUG)
        try:
            # Here goes your original run() code
        except Exception:
            logger.exception('whoopsie')
```

What this code does:

1. Creates a special logger which will transmit it's information to the main process and dump it to stderr (console by default).
2. Configures this logger to report everything, including some internal `multiprocessing` module events (just in case as you probably don't need them).
3. Wraps your entire code in catch-all statement so whatever happens there cannot escape your notice.
4. Runs `.exception()` method on the logger, which not only logs the message (it's meaningless anyway as we don't know what actually happens) but most importantly logs the entire error traceback - which we actually need.